# Can you use a windows server in combination with a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, windows-server-2012, high-availability

I am going to make a GUI with WPF because then I can use MahApps.Metro, which makes my application pretty. This application will be installed on computers and should be available 24/7.So I thought using a windows server would be a good idea.

But some say that it is a bad idea. What should i use instead? I really want to make this application 24/7 available.

Comment: Are you asking if your app can be hosted on a server? Or whether the **services** the app consumes can be hosted on a server?

Comment: @MikeEason I think both? I am sorry if don't understand what i don't understand :( It's just so much information and i don't know where to begin.

Comment: What exactly needs to be *24/7 available*? What does the application *do*?

Comment: @MikeEason. It needs to get data 24/7, in my application it is a constant stream of reported phishing mails. It is going to be a anti phishing mail application.

Answer (score 2):

--  It needs to get data 24/7, in my application it is a constant stream of reported phishing mails. It is going to be a anti phishing mail application --

You doesn't need a WPF GUI running 24/7. 
You need a window service that running 24/7 that collect all the details you want into database (and sending out alert if required). And another WPF Gui only need to load up the data from database whenever the user wants. Don't mix up the 2 different parts of module into 1

Answer (score 1):

Yes indeed you can use a a WPF Application with a Server.
For example i was programming a C# Chat Server/Client side and i just made a ConsoleApplication for the Server Side and on the Client side i had a nice looking GUI for the Client. But if you can avoid using a server i would, because you will have to run a server 24/7 and this usually costs a lot of money.

Edit: If you only need data for the client use a database server i recommend MySQL

Sry for my bad english i am German